# Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:3000/api/graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I have started Node server and Mongod and trying to run sample programs.

Output from command prompts:

***mongod*** command prompt:

```
2018-06-17T23:38:19.464+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic 
data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2018-06-17T23:38:19.466+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for 
connections on port 27017
```

**mongo** command prompt:

MongoDB shell version v3.6.5

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

I am able to run commands in mongo shell by starting mongo from command prompt. 
But sample program is throwing below exception.

http://localhost:3000/api/graphql

```
[0] [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/graphql from 
localhost:3000 to http://localhost:4040 (ECONNREFUSED) 
(https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I am not sure that no other process is running on 4040 port.

let me know how to resolve this issue.

Update on sequence of steps:

```
 install npm
 install mongodb
 $ git clone https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git
 $ cd mean
 $ npm install && npm start

 npm start will open default home page :  http://localhost:3000/
 On home page, click on GraphQL browser
```

Comment: You have posted only errors... please post some code... Did you try `localhost:4040/graphql` pasting on your browser? It will show whether the connection is established or not

Comment: It's example code from Node.js. There is one link GraphQL in default home page(http://localhost:3000 ) browser which calls http://localhost:3000/api/graphql

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by replacing localhost with [::1].

```
http://[::1]:3000
```